# Combine Tokens in elasticsearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I need to customize a tokenizer (or add a filter later in the stream) in a way that it combines multiple tokens into one when certain conditions are met: 
I would like to use the standard tokenizer but have two words with the "&" symbol in between combined into one token.

Example:
The string `R & D` should end up as a token `r d`. The standard tokenizer is dropping the "&", resulting in the separate tokens `r`, `d`. The whitespace tokenizer results in the three tokens `R`, `&`, `D`.

I can't just use a keyword tokenizer and then drop the "&" since I do need this to work within a longer piece of text (that is why I would like to start with the standard tokenizer as default)

Comment: I think your description of the requirements is not complete. I understand that you need to remove `&` and this could easily be done with a [char filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-charfilters.html)  and `keyword` analyzer. But then you say "I can't just use a keyword tokenizer and then drop the "&" since I do need this to work within a longer piece of text (that is why I would like to start with the standard tokenizer as default)". Can you give some examples of input text and list of terms that ES should come up with?

Comment: More elaborate example:
"The quick brown fox does R&D as well as sales." should become `the` `quick` `brown` `fox` `does` `r d` `as` `well` `as` `sales`

Comment: Note that, even though it doesn't seem like much, is a big difference between text input as "R & D" and "R&D". While the first is much more difficult to handle, the second is easier. Also, as an output, you always want "r d"? Meaning a white space between "r" and "d"?

Comment: yes, I'd want the space between r and d. And good catch with the space. The original source does have the spaces in there. so "R & D" would need to be handled properly.